# Ansible implementatipn: how to dispatch reverse proxy and backend server configuration efficiently?

Tags: ansible, reverse-proxy, ansible-inventory

I'm wondering what is the best practice when deploying with Ansible this kind of situation (which is quite common):

- **my.domain.com** DNS rule must resolve to my proxy server
- the proxy server (nginx or whatever) serves content from my backend server

How to dispatch configuration to each server?

What I've done so far:

- **host_var/my.domain.com** -> nginx vhost configuration
- **host_var/my.backend.com** -> backend configuration

This choice is quite annoying, because it makes me create 2 subdomains each time:

- **my.domain.com** to resolve and store proxy configuration
- **my.backend.com** to resolve and store backend configuration

It seems OK for 1 single example, but when dealing with lots of services (think microservices) it seems to me it could be improved.

Do you think about another possible implementation?

Comment: @techraf I edited to make the question more straightforward.

Comment: As I'm asking about implementation, and providing technical details about mine, my post is definitely legitimate. If not, please provide me the rule which says otherwise, and redirect me to the right channel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group redundant configuration you have to put your servers in a group in your inventory file.

```
[frontend]
f1 ansible_host=10.0.0.1
f2 ansible_host=10.0.0.2

[backend]
b1 ansible_host=10.0.1.1
b2 ansible_host=10.0.1.2
```

And then you create two files

- `group_vars/frontend.yml`
- `group_vars/backend.yml`

in which you put the configuration for the frontend and backend servers.

Ansible does not require, that you use any domain at all.

Comment: Yes I'm already using groups to centralize configuration common for each backend/frontend, but this doesn't prevent from creating 2 subdomains for each backend.